# Using Clojurescript thread-first macros with Javascript Interop

Tags: javascript, clojure, macros, clojurescript

Is it possible to use the "thread-first" macro if any of the required forms are part of a Javascript interop?

For example, if you wanted to group inputs in ranges of size 10, you might have something like the following:

```
(defn get-size [i]
  (-> i
      (/ 10)
      (.ceil js/Math)))
```

However, this doesn't work as presumably the result after division gets passed to `.ceil` as if it were a function. Wrapping the last form in extra parenthesis to try and have it evaluated as a single function expression also does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->` & friends don't care whether the expressions they operate on are related to interop or not – they only see the forms as data structures and transform them according to simple rules.

The reason your example doesn't work is that it attempts to call a method called `ceil` on the number with `js/Math` as the argument rather than calling the method `Math.ceil` on the number:

1. `(-> i (/ 10) (.ceil js/Math))`
2. `(-> (/ i 10) (.ceil js/Math))`
3. `(.ceil (/ i 10) js/Math)`

This would work:

```
(-> i (/ 10) (->> (.ceil js/Math)))
```

As would the anonymous function approach with the correct argument order:

```
(-> i (/ 10) (#(.ceil js/Math %)))
```

For more complex cases with initial arguments to `->` more complex than just `i` you might find `as->` quite useful.